# Multiple filters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

I am using http://mixitup.io/ library to provide filtering for my simple list of items. Everything works fine, except one thing: multiple level filters which I need.

I have two types of filtering, one is based on "type", and one on "manufacturer". So, lets say I want to show "typeA" from "manufacturer1", or some other combination. Items would need to satisfy both of those to be shown on the list.

I can't get that to work, and upon clicking on the filters, I can show only "typeA", which will include all manufacturers, or "manufacturerA", which shows multiple types, but that's not what I want.

I have included the jsfiddle with the code I have now here: http://jsfiddle.net/QtQnB/62/

For the filters, I used this:

```
<div id="filter">
    <span>Type</span>
    <ul class="filter-list">
        <li data-filter="lemon" class="filter" data-dimension="type"><a href="#">Lemon</a></li>
        <li data-filter="orange" class="filter" data-dimension="type"><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
        <li data-filter="apple" class="filter" data-dimension="type"><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    </ul>


    <span>Manufacturer</span>
    <ul class="filter-list">
        <li data-filter="1" class="filter" data-dimension="manufacturer"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li data-filter="2" class="filter" data-dimension="manufacturer"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The item list is as follows:

```
<ul id="grid">
    <li class="mix lemon small">
        <h3> small Lemon</h3>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </li>
    <li class="mix orange small">
        <h3>small Orange</h3>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </li>
    <li class="mix apple medium">
        <h3>medium Apple</h3>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </li>
    <li class="mix lemon big">
        <h3>big Lemon</h3>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </li>
    <li class="mix orange medium">
        <h3>medium Orange</h3>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </li>
    <li class="mix apple big">
        <h3>big Apple</h3>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then the simple js code to initialize the mixitup, load initial items and try to apply the filter for multiple categories with the last line, which is not working:

```
$('#grid').mixitup({
    showOnLoad: "2 orange",
    filterLogic : 'and'});

var $filters = $('.filter-list').find('li'), dimensions = {type: 'orange', manufacturer: '2' };


$filters.on('click',function(){
var $t = $(this),
    dimension = $t.attr('data-dimension'),
    filter = $t.attr('data-filter');
    console.info("dimension: "+dimension);
    console.info("filter "+filter);
    console.info("current filter for this cat: "+dimensions[dimension]);
    dimensions[dimension] = filter;
    console.info("selected filter for this cat: "+dimensions[dimension]);
    console.info("type: "+ dimensions['type']);
    console.info("manufacturer: "+ dimensions['manufacturer']);
    var filterString = dimensions['type'] + " " + dimensions['manufacturer'];



$('#grid').mixitup('filter',filterString);
});
```

I looked at other questions, and example they have provided with the library, but I simply cant get this to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your fault! It took me an hour to figure out, but it turns out that there are existing click events that you have to remove first. I don't know why their examples don't show it.

If you add `$filters.unbind('click');` after your `var $filters...` line, it'll work.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QtQnB/63/)

Comment: This seems to be it. I also spent a couple of hours on this and was really frazzled by the whole "OH COME ON WHY WONT YOU FILTER IT" thing. Thank you!

For some reason, the showOnLoad option doesn't work properly, and I have to do 
`$('[data-filter="orange"]').click();`
`$('[data-filter="2"]').click();`

That makes the filter load my initial list that I need, since `showOnLoad: "orange 2"` doesn't do anything.

Comment: The solution I found to initial load is to call the filter straight after the initialisation: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QtQnB/64/).