# Mixitup jquery multiple filters css of controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the method to set up multiple filtering in mixitup described here:

[Multiple filters in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537742/multiple-filters-in-jquery?rq=1)

Unfortunately I can't get the active filters highlighted with css. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LdVJv/

Help would be appreciated

**html**

```
    <div id="filter"> <span>Filter</span>

    <ul class="filter-list">
        <li data-filter="mix" class="filter" data-dimension="type"><a href="#">all</a>
        </li>
        <li data-filter="lemon" class="filter" data-dimension="type"><a href="#">Lemon</a>
        </li>
        <li data-filter="orange" class="filter" data-dimension="type"><a href="#">Orange</a>
        </li>
        <li data-filter="apple" class="filter" data-dimension="type"><a href="#">Apple</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="filter"> <span>Filter</span>

    <ul class="filter-list">
        <li data-filter="mix" class="filter" data-dimension="manufacturer"><a href="#">all</a>
        </li>
        <li data-filter="1" class="filter" data-dimension="manufacturer"><a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li data-filter="2" class="filter" data-dimension="manufacturer"><a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul id="grid">
    <li class="mix lemon 2">
         <h3>Lemon</h3>

        <p>2</p>
    </li>
    <li class="mix orange 1">
         <h3>Orange</h3>

        <p>1</p>
    </li>
    <li class="mix orange 2">
         <h3>Orange</h3>

        <p>2</p>
    </li>
    <li class="mix apple 1">
         <h3>Apple</h3>

        <p>1</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Wait until all images load
function imgLoaded(img) {
    var $img = $(img);
    $img.closest('.img_wrapper').addClass('loaded');
}

// Start mixitup
$('#grid').mixitup();

var $filters = $('.filter-list').find('li'),
    dimensions = {
        type: '',
        manufacturer: ''
    };

$filters.unbind('click');

$filters.on('click', function () {
    var $t = $(this),
        dimension = $t.attr('data-dimension'),
        filter = $t.attr('data-filter');
    console.info("dimension: " + dimension);
    console.info("filter " + filter);
    console.info("current filter for this cat: " + dimensions[dimension]);
    dimensions[dimension] = filter;
    console.info("selected filter for this cat: " + dimensions[dimension]);
    console.info("type: " + dimensions['type']);
    console.info("manufacturer: " + dimensions['manufacturer']);


    $('#grid').mixitup('filter', [dimensions['type'], dimensions['manufacturer']]);
});
```

**css**

```
    li {
    list-style: none;
}
#grid .mix {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.filter-list li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: square;
}
.filter-list li.active {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: _“Unfortunately I can't get the active filters highlighted with css”_ – so you want to give the class `active` to the filters that are applied? Well then what does _“can’t get it to work”_ mean – because I don’t see you even _trying_ to do that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#grid').mixitup({
  controls: {
    toggleFilterButtons: true,
    toggleLogic: 'or',
    activeClass: 'active'
  }
}
```

You need to pass the name of the class you want the active buttons to have when instantiating mixitup.